# Circular Argument in Proof of Circumference of a Circle using Calculus

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, circles

I have some doubts in this demonstration:

> Prove the Circumference of a Circle is $C=2 \pi r$
>
> The equation of a circle is
>
> $(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2 $
>
> To do computations easier let's consider a circle centered in the
> origin (0,0)
>
> $x^2 + y^2 = r^2 $
>
> Solving for y we have:
>
> $y = \pm \sqrt{r^2-x^2} $
>
> We know from calculus that we can compute the arc lenght of curves by
> using the next formula
>
> $L= \int dL = \int \sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2} dx$
>
> Let's compute the arc length of half a circle ($ L_{hC}  $), to do
> that we take the positive solution of the equation of the circle
>
> $y = \sqrt{r^2-x^2}  $
>
> We multiply the final result by two to have the complete answer ($ L_C = 2 L_{hC} $)
>
> So we have
>
> $L_{hC} = \int_{-r}^r  \sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx}^2)}dx ​$
>
> Let's ​compute the derivative of y by doing a change of variable
>
> $u=r^2 -x^2$
>
> $du=-2xdx$
>
> So
>
> $y=\sqrt{u}$
>
> Deriving
>
> $\frac{dy}{du} = \frac{1}{2} (u)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$
>
> $\frac{dy}{dx} = -x(r^2-x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}   $
>
> Placing this result
>
> $L_{hC} = \int_{-r}^r \sqrt{1 + (-x(r^2 - x^2)^{- \frac{1}{2} } )^2 }dx $
>
> $L_{hC} = \int_{-r}^r \sqrt{1+ x^2(r^2-x^2)^{-1}} dx$
>
> $L_{hC} = \int_{-r}^r \sqrt{\frac{r^2}{r^2 - x^2}}dx =\int_{-r}^r \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2 - x^2}} dx$
>
> $L_{hC} =  r  \int_{-r}^r \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2 - x^2}} dx$
>
> Using trigonometric substitution ($h=r$, $c1=\sqrt{r^2 -x^2}$, $c2=x$)
>
> $ \sin \theta = \frac{x}{r} $
>
> $ x = r \sin \theta $
>
> $ dx = r \cos \theta d \theta $
>
> $ \theta = \arcsin (\frac{x}{r})   $
>
> We also have:
>
> $ \cos \theta = \frac{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}{r}    $
>
> $ r\cos \theta = \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}   $
>
> Replacing in the integral and changing the integral limits
>
> $ L_{hC} = r \int_{\arcsin(-1)}^{\arcsin(1)} \frac{r\cos \theta}{r\cos \theta} d\theta $
>
> $ L_{hC} = r \int_{- \frac{\pi}{2}}^{ \frac{\pi}{2}} d \theta = r \theta \bigg|_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} = r(\frac{\pi}{2} - (- \frac{\pi}{2}) ) = r \pi $
>
> Since $ L_C = 2 L_{hC} $ we have $ L_C = 2 \pi r  $
>
> So we prove that the Circumference of a Circle is $C=2 \pi r$

My problem with this demonstration is that it looks like we are using what we are trying to prove in the proof itself.
How do we know that $\arcsin(1)= \frac{\pi}{2}$?

We're using angles in radians. How do we know that the angle of a whole circle is equal to $2\pi$ radians? this piece of information is what we are trying to demonstrate

Comment: Proving the circumference of a circle? You realise that $\pi$, the Archimedean constant, is *by definition* the number such that the circumference is $2\pi r$... calculus could only become relevant to prove the area of a circle! Pi is the circumference divided by the diameter

Comment: Yes, but then, this calculus proof that appears in many places is irrelevant

Comment: You are right: $\arcsin(1)=\pi/2$ has no meaning without a definition of $\pi$, a definition which is almost exactly the statement $C=2\pi r$ - the whole argument here is, well, circular, not to mention pointless!

Comment: This is a proof that many people uses. I think they should say that the argument is circular or pointless as you mention

Comment: I’m very curious - who is many people? The only motivation for this proof that I can see is that this shows that maths is generally self-consistent. $\arcsin(1)=\pi/2$ comes back to prove itself via a little calculus detour

Comment: well, for example, you just have to search in youtube "Circumference of a Circle Proof" to find some videos using the same calculus argument e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nx6OG7xABqA, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bU-54NTak5A, etc...

Comment: Well, these youtubers are presumably just looking for more revenue - for any circumference of the circle “proof” is tautological at best, unless you want to express it in terms other than $\pi$. If I had the powers, I would vote to close this question. $C=2\pi r$ by definition and any “proof” of this almost certainly will subtly include this fact as part of the “proof”, making any argument circular. Moreover, in maths it is very important to accept definitions, and prove their consequences and implications instead

Comment: If you want a correct proof, you first have to tell us what definitions you already have. For example, how did you define $\pi$? Did you already define $\sin,\cos, \arcsin$? In what order did you define things? What properties of these functions have you already proven. Trigonometry is such a large subject that there are MANY equivalent ways of describing/presenting it, all of them logical. The dangerous part is if you look at two different approaches and try to cross-examine them without having fully understood either one (that's when everything starts to look circular and illogical).

Comment: One example for what peek-a-boo said, you could define $\pi$ and the trigonometric functions starting from complex exponentiation, which you could define via taylor series for example. How legitimate the proof you posted very much depends on how you define things.

Comment: @FShrike it is quite possible to start off with defining sin and cos by their series definition and then show that there is a unique number $\pi \in (0,4)$ such that $\operatorname{sin}(\pi)=0, e^{2\pi i }=1, \operatorname{cos}(\pi / 4)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Then it does make sense to prove that the circumference of a circle is $2\pi r$.
It just depends on what definitions you are using, as peek-a-boo mentioned

Comment: @DieDauphin Can you prove $\arcsin 1=\pi/2$? If yes, do you need to know the circumference of a circle in the proof?

Answer (score 1):

Before we get into why $\arcsin(1)$ = $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and a full rotation = 360˚ = 2$\pi$ radians, lets look at how radians work:

A angle in **radians** allows us to form a relationship between the `angle`, the `radii` and the `arc length` (which is harder to do in degrees).

The relationship is something like this:

[Circle Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyYxA.png)

where the arc length is **relative** to the angle is:

**arc length** = **angle** (in radians) $\times$ **radius**

$\therefore$ for `1 radian`, arc length = radius.

**Now to answer your question of**: `How do we know that the angle of a whole circle is equal to 2 radians?`

If according to the proof in your question, where the `circumference` of the circle, **which is equal the `arc length` of the entire circle**, = **2$\pi r$**, and our equation,

$\mathbf L$ = $\theta$ * r, where r = radius, $\theta$ = angle in radians and $\mathbf L$ = arc length:

If,

$\mathbf L$ = $\theta$ * r,

$\theta$ = $\frac{\mathbf L}{r}$

But again,

circumference = full arc length = $2\pi r$

$\therefore$  $\theta$ (full) = $\frac{2\pi r}{r}$ = $\mathbf2\mathbf\pi$

The relationship between `angle` and `length` is also seen in `Trigonometry`:

[This picture should be pretty much self explanatory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEllG.png)

This shows that the `sine` and `cosine` of an angle is the ratio of the two sides of a triangle.

**Moving to your other question**: `How do we know that arcsin(1)=  / 2?`

To prove this, we first need to prove its inverse: $\sin{(\frac{\pi}{2})} = 1$:

**The Unit Circle**:

[Unit Circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YeWY.png)

we can see that:

[$\sin(\theta) = y$ (coordinate)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLMbd.png)

Basically above, we have applied the basic laws of `Trigonometry` from the right angled triangle, where,

$\sin(\theta) = \frac{opposite}{hypotenuse}$,

but in a unit circle the `hypotenuse` = `radius` = `1`

So, $\sin(\theta) = \frac{opposite}{hypotenuse}$ = $\frac{opposite}{1}$ = ${opposite}$;

We can tell that $\sin{(\frac{\pi}{2} = 90˚)} = 1$ by inferring; if `y` is `1` and $\sin(\theta) = opposite$ = y,

$\theta$ = 90˚ `counter-clockwise` from the `x-axis` (positive direction from the x-axis).

When $\theta$ = 90˚, on the unit circle, the triangle will look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nJP6.png)... wait... not really a triangle is it?

Visually, a triangle does not exists when two of the angles in a right angle triangle are 90˚ (there will not be a third angle, and a triangle cannot exist without three angles), as the rule of *sum of all **three** angles = 180˚* holds true.

However, by looking at the trend we can tell that as $\theta$ approaches `90˚`, $\sin(\theta)$ approaches `1`, giving the follow expression:

$\lim_{\theta\to 90˚} \sin{(\theta)} = 1$

(To note: angles above 90˚ repeat the trend (look at the `sine graph / curve` for more info);

--> The **opposite approaches the length of the hypotenuse or radius**.

[You can also use the sine curve on a cartesian plane to prove this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiqEp.png)
(where $y = \sin{(x)}$)

Hope this helps :) !!